# External website in .NET and Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, .net, active-directory

I'm building a website and I need authenticate a User using Active Directory.

My website is on a different network and IP from the Server where the Active Directory is running (it is in a completely different network and domain).

I would like to know if is possible build an Login Page which could authenticate an User on a remote AD.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not deploy any web services on an Active Directory server.

You can use System.Directoryservices.Accountmanagement namespace classes (.NET 4) or using ADSI.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it would be to use LDAP to validate the supplied user credentials. [Here is an example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326340) from Microsoft on how you could do it.

Comment: Can we build an App , on .NET 4.5 which has user, groups roles defined in SQL DB and based on Groups against that user , end user can see Folders and Files on another server where Group is same as defined in DB.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation to this, and the only way I could think to do it was like this:

- Create a very small website on the server with Active Directory, which uses windows authentication
- Have this website redirect to your main website, with some form of login key in the URL (best if generated on the fly) if the user authenticated.

Don't think there is any way for you to use the authentication over the external website other than along these lines.